# vbscript update excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

I've looked on many sites, including all the questions that came up when I entered my title, and I can't seem to get my program to work. It activates the spreadsheet, but no data prints.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel, objWorkbook
Dim strTIN, strName, strFName, strLName, strState, strEmpID, strRecDate, strComment

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\lpeder6\Desktop\Important Info\Data tracking.xlsx")

CopyData

Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing

'---------------CopyData - Copies required data-----------------

Sub CopyData()

    strTIN = "2-123456789-00005"
    strName = "Smith        John   "
    strState = "MN"
    strEmpID = "S987654321"
    strRecDate = "04/02/2015"
    strComment = "This is all that is in my comment."
    strLName = Trim(Left(strName, 10))
    strFName = Trim(Right(strName, 15))
    strName = strLName & " " & strFName

    objExcel.Visible = True

    objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = strTIN
    objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value = strName
    objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value = strState
    objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4).Value = strEmpID
    objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5).Value = strRecDate
    objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6).Value = strComment
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Prints where? The code does not seem to have any print related commands.

Comment: By "prints", I mean entering the data into the Excel spreadsheet. It's supposed to print the data into each cell, but nothing gets entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *'no data prints'*, I'm assuming that you mean the data you input is not stored. This is because you are not saving the workbook as you close it. Change one line in the sub to:

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close true
```

See [Workbook.Close Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for full syntax reference.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was overlooking. :)